# Want to Display invocation result where i called the Procedure

Tags: javascript, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
  {
     "name": "pradeep",
     "password": 123,
     "timestamp": "2014-04-08T12:58:45.000Z"
  },
  {
     "name": "dileep",
     "password": 1234,
     "timestamp": "2014-04-08T13:00:52.000Z"
  }
```

]
}

I have called my procedure and this invocation result i have got.Now i need to display it in the console where i called my procedure(not in client Side).so hw can i achieve this.And alert wont work their so which API i Should use.

Comment: What do you mean by "console"?

Comment: You can see it in your BROWSER console (not eclipse), using javascript's console.log

Comment: Also, please study basic javascript before your next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot display the response from the adapter invocation in the Eclipse console.
There is no meaning in displaying it in the Eclipse console.

You can see it in the following locations:

1. By right-clicking on the adapter and choosing Run As > Invoke Worklight procedure.

   This will open a browser window and will display the result
2. By invoking it via `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` and parsing the result, and display it in your app
3. By using console.log to print the result, and then press F12 to open the Chrome Dev Tools (for example) >> Network tab >> pick the response >> Response tab

Comment: Can we use WL.Logger.Log

Comment: Use WL.Logger.debug; PLEASE - read the WORKLIGHT DOCUMENTATION. You've been pretty much asking the SAME question for some 5 times now.